# Using functions from a class in another file to a class in my second file, python3

Tags: python-3.4

I have two python files, one is the gui, the other  contains all of the functions, say i have a class named Backend like in the code below, and one of its functions is "print1(self)", and i want to use that "print1" function inside of the second file in the class named retranslateUi(self, Form), how would i do it?

First file

```
__author__ = 'Richard'
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('realscheduler.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('pragma foreign_keys = ON;')
class Backend:
    def print1(self):
        print('Works')
```

Second file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.4.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Labellabellabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Print"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  to import the first file into the second one as `import first_filename as t` then create class object `p=t.classname` then use any function you want which is declared in the class

Answer (score 1):

First you should create a main entry point to the application like so. I will call it `app.py` and the generated Qt Designer file `view.py` for this example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)

# importing the GUI from the designer file
from view import Ui_MainWindow

# importing the database file Backend class
from database import Backend

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # this will connect your push button the the function
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Backend.print1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("app name")
    QCoreApplication.setApplicationVersion("app version")
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("Your name")
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("Your URL")

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Main()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PyQt follows the Model-View architecture so this is a nice way to bind your functionality / data away from the graphical components of the application.